# Allow only 11 or 16 alphanumerical characters PHP

Tags: php, regex

How can I get a string that only contains maximum of 11 or 16 characters of a regex pattern ?

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $str) == 1) {
        echo 'Invalid Characters';
    }
    echo 'Valid characters';
```

**if Numeric, maximum length of 16 digits, 
If alpha-numeric, maximum length of 11 characters**

Eg: Numeric = 0825551234

Eg: alpha-numeric =  1800House

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z(11|16)]+$/`

Comment: 11 or 16 = `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{5})?$` ... 11 to 16 = `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11,16}$`

Comment: Why not use `length` or `count` with regex.

Comment: @Mariano first one is correct where the second is not.

Comment: @AvinashRaj He has mentioned _"11 to 16 ="_

Comment: @Avinash. it does not accept the string "PETER11"

Comment: @dev1234 Why should it? You've said _"string that only contains 11 or 16 characters"_

Comment: it can contain a maximum of 11 or 16

Comment: @Tushar sorry. can contain maximum of 11 or 16

Comment: @dev1234 _maximum of 11 or 16_, so, 12, 13, 14, 15 characters are allowed? Please add some valid string formats.

Comment: @Tushar yes allowed.

Comment: may be `minimum of 11 and maximum of 16`?

Comment: @Mariano sorry, you are correct. we should make it maximum length of 16

Comment: Use `{11,16}` quantificator

Comment: 5 to 16 = `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,16}$`

Comment: I give up! But I'm sure you can now get your solution by reading all the attempts to answer your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of outlining the rest of your requirements in comments you should update your question. Based on what I read, try this: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,16}$/`

Alpha-numeric, minimum 5 and maximum 16 characters repetition.

Comment: This is not working. Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^'

Comment: use delimeters`"/regexp/"`

Comment: @dev1234 really? You want me to retype your entire code set just to point out the exact RegEx? I gave you a regular expression, how you use it and where is up to you. I'll update the answer to contain delimiters, Got forbid someone else doesn't figure that out from the question, comments and this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Regexp, but for me this is an answer for your question

```
if(preg_match("/^\d{1,16}$/", "12345678123456781") == 1)
{
echo "Numeric";
}
else if(preg_match("/^([\w\_]{1,11})$/", "qweqweqweqwe") == 1)
{
echo "Alphanumeric";
}
else
{
echo("some other stuff");
}
```

If you don't want to escape underscores, just replace second regexp with this `/^(\w{1,11})$/`

Comment: +1 although, the "== 1" is redundant in PHP - but splitting the two tests is probably the better way. It feels good when you can get clever with regex - but it can quickly spiral into less obvious logic

Comment: The `\w` includes `_` which isn't an alphanumerical character. Also `_` is not a special character in regex so it won't/wouldn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

> if Numeric, maximum length of 16 digits, If alpha-numeric, maximum
>   length of 11 characters

This should do it:

```
<?php

//$string="0123456789012345";/* 16 digits */
$string="012345abcde";       /* 11 alpha-numeric */

if( preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,16}$|^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,11}$/", $string) )
{
  echo 'valid Characters';
}
else
{
  echo 'Invalid characters';
}
```

Quality Assurance: https://3v4l.org/1c2KD

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(ctype_digit($this->smsSenderId) && strlen($this->smsSenderId) > 16){
         //'too long (maximum is 16 numeric characters)';
        }
        // alpha numeric can contain 11 characters
        else if(strlen($this->smsSenderId) > 11){
            //'too long (maximum is 11 alpha-numeric characters)';
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{4,11}$/", $this->smsSenderId) == 1){
            //'Invalid characters. Eg: 0825551234 or 1800House';
        }
```

Comment: Why `{4,11}`, is there a minimum requirement I missed for alphanumerical?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without using a regex at all.

```
$strings = array('0825551234', '1800House', '111111111111111', 'aaaaaaaaaaa', '12!1adfas');
foreach($strings as $string){
echo "Testing for: $string";
if((is_numeric($string) && strlen($string) <=16) || (ctype_alnum($string) && strlen($string) <=11)) {
     echo ' true' . "\n";
} else {
     echo ' false' . "\n";
}
}
```

Output:

```
Testing for: 0825551234 true
Testing for: 1800House true
Testing for: 111111111111111 true
Testing for: aaaaaaaaaaa true
Testing for: 12!1adfas false
```

Or if you needed to regex:

```
$strings = array('0825551234', '1800House', '11122111111111111', 'aaaaaaaaaaa', '12!1adfas');
foreach($strings as $string){
echo "Testing for: $string";
if(preg_match('~^(\d{1,16}|[a-z0-9]{1,11})$~i', $string)) {
     echo ' true' . "\n";
} else {
     echo ' false' . "\n";
}
}
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/mN1aF8/1